# ¿Como puedo "leer los valores" de este array en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Vengo de una consulta mysql y hago un `array_push($miarray, $campos)` dentro de un `while`.... ya fuera del `while`, realizo un `$resultados = print_r($miarray, true); echo $resultados;` y me "imprime" esto:

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [titulo] => LIBRO-1 [texto] => aquí un texto largo ) [1] => s 
 tdClass Object ( [titulo] => LIBRO-2 [texto] => aquí otro texto largo ) [2] => stdClass Object ( 
 [titulo] => LIBRO-3 [texto] => aquí otro texto largo ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [titulo] => 
 LIBRO-4 [texto] => aquí otro texto largo ) )
```

¿Como puedeo leer esto? intente lo siguiente pero no me funciono: `$leer = $resultados[1]->titulo;`

Comment: @BetaM No, no me muestra nada, tampoco error.

Comment: Simplemente una nota, dado que hablas de una consulta a la base de datos, si no necesitas los datos para portarlos a otro lado, no conviene guardar los resultados para imprimirlos a continuación, puedes imprimirlos dentro del mismo `while` o bucle que usas para extraer cada fila obtenida, me refiero al bucle donde aplicas el `fetch`, ahí mismo puedes ir mostrando cada dato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observaciones:

- Lo que ahí obtienes es un arreglo de objetos
- Necesitas:

  - Iterar los registros con algún ciclo por ejemplo `foreach()`
- Una vez dentro de la estructura del ciclo, necesitas indicar a que clave o claves deseas acceder

  - No olvides que como son objetos, entonces la sintaxis es: `$variable->clave`

Entonces:

```
foreach ($miarray as $resultado) {
    echo $resultado->titulo;
    echo $resultado->texto;
}
```

Comment: Si lo hago con `foreach ($miarray as $xvariable)` si funciona así como lo indicas, pero yo paso el array a "una variable" `$resultados` con `$resultados = print_r($miarray, true);` , para leerlo en cualquier otra parte, pero no lo lee así: `foreach ($resultados as $xvariable)`, no me aparece nada.

Comment: Por ejemplo si lo hago así, me funciona el "ciclo" `for($i=0; $i<count($miarray); $i++){ $prueba1 = $miarray[$i]->titulo; $prueba2 = $miarray[$i]->texto;` Pero ya no lo puedo leer de esta forma: `for($i=0; $i<count($resultados); $i++){ $prueba1 = $resultadosy[$i]->titulo; $prueba2 = $resultados[$i]->texto;` para leerlo en otro php o en otro lugar. Lo paso a otro php con session_start(); en `$_SESSION['prueba'] = $resultados;`

Comment: Pues es que está asignación `$resultados = print_r($miarray, true);` no me parece lógica, es decir para que igualas a una variable la impresión de una estructura de datos?, No debería ser solo contra `$miarray` ?

Comment: ¡Tienes toda la razón! envié en el `session_start(); $_SESSION['prueba'] = $miarray;` y ya funciono perfecto el "for" en el otro php. ¡Mil gracias!